# Will mobile web apps ever gain bookmark distribution inside of the Facebook native iOS app?

Tags: facebook, html, mobile, web

I think bookmark distribution inside the Facebook native iOS app is a great opportunity. However, based on the table at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/support/, it appears that option is only available to native iOS apps. Does anyone know if there are future plans to make web app bookmarks available inside the native app?

Comment: Did you mean to say that bookmark distribution is available to every platform _except_ iOS native? It's only available to iOS users visiting the mobile website.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that the bookmark feature within the native iOS Facebook app violates Apple's policies regarding content on their platform, i.e. a web app bookmarked within the Facebook native app would represent a different user experience from the one that was cleared by Apple when they let the Facebook app onto the App Store.

If this is the case, there will be no bookmarks available in the native app unless Apple changes their policy, or grants Facebook a waiver.